# getElementsByClassName VS getElementById in a custom funcion in combination with jquery.maphilight.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

In this simple page my functions "enlargeImg" and "resetImg" work using "getElementsByClassName" but not with "getElementById"  (see commented lines) since when I included jquery.maphilight.min.js

Can you explain me why and tell me how to use "getElementById" without conflicts?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
</style>
<script>
     // Function to set image dimensions
     function enlargeImg() {
     //document.getElementById("img1").style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
     document.getElementsByClassName('map')[0].style.transform = "scale(1.5)";

     }
     // Function to reset image dimensions
     function resetImg() {
     //document.getElementById("img1").style.transform = "scale(1.0)";
     document.getElementsByClassName('map')[0].style.transform = "scale(1.0)";   
     }
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://projects.davidlynch.org/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {$('.map').maphilight();});</script>


        <!-- script to set display property -->

</head>

<body>

<button onclick="enlargeImg()">Zoom</button>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button onclick="resetImg()">Reset</button>
<br/>

<div class="center">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" class="map" id="img1">

<map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/computer.htm" target="_blank">
  <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/phone.htm" target="_blank">
  <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/coffee.htm" target="_blank">
</map>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Dylan666 `maphilight`

```
$(function() {$('.map').maphilight();});
```

adding the exernal div to your `<img />` tag, hence your image is not enlarging it's enlarging the first map class and its the `<div>` which outside the `<img />` tag.
That's why it's not working as what you thinking like.

For more clear you can change the class of img and also in js try below snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.mapElm1').maphilight();
  $('.mapElm1').attr('id', 'img1');
});
function enlargeImg() {
  document.getElementById('img1').style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
}
function resetImg() {
  document.getElementById('img1').style.transform = "scale(1.0)"; 
}
```

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://projects.davidlynch.org/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="enlargeImg()">Zoom</button><br/>
<button onclick="resetImg()">Reset</button>
<br/>
<div class="center">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" class="mapElm1" >
    <map name="workmap">
        <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/computer.htm" target="_blank">
        <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/phone.htm" target="_blank">
        <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/coffee.htm" target="_blank">
    </map>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh, thank for your help but i need to use `getElementById("img1")` and not `getElementsByClassName('mapElm1')[0]`. Could you show me the code? I can't use it even deleting the `<div>`

Comment: Hi Dylan666, I have updated the code snippet try once. 
There is div created by maphilight(); we have added id to them. You can try this and let me know.

Comment: Thank you, adding `$('.mapElm1').attr('id', 'img1');`  made it work!